# Python mysql-connector SELECT in loop returns outdated result

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, loops, mysql-connector

I'm using mysql-connector to run a `SELECT` query in a while loop to look for new jobs.

```
import mysql.connector

while True:
        sql.execute("select id, mailing_list, account_list, template from dom_campaigns where status = 0")
        campaigns = sql.fetchall()
```

If I insert a row into the table and start the script, it processes it. However, if I start the script and then insert a row while the script is running, it never returns it as a result of `fetchall()`. I have to stop/start the script for it to show up.

Why is it doing this and how can I get it to fetch the row if it's inserted while the script is running?

Comment: Are you sure you're commiting the insert? If not it will only be visible from the same session.

Comment: @SimonN Yes. It's inserted via a PHP script and I can see it in the table. The Python script will return it but only if I restart the PY script.

Comment: Same thing happens if I manually insert the row.